Automatic Jenkins view creation
I am using the latest version of Jenkins, 2.440.3
I need to know if there is a possibility of creating view automatically through command line rather than GUI.

The Jenkins CLI is pretty limited and doesn't have the ability to create a view. However, you should be able to do this by calling the Jenkins API. Take a look at this comment. Basically, the solution is run curl commands that create the view in the config.xml, fetch the config.xml, then POST it back so that it updates the view:
curl -vvv -X POST -d @view.xml -H "Content-Type: text/xml" http://localhost:8080/jenkins/createView?name=MyView

curl http://localhost:8080/jenkins/view/MyView/config.xml

curl -X POST -d @view.xml -H "Content-Type: text/xml" http://localhost:8080/jenkins/view/MyView/config.xml

